# "Internal dummy connection" in log, MaxClient reached, server crashes. Opinions?

Tags: apache2, redhat

I am trying to streamline a server of a clients. After downloading the access_log files, I noticed that there were an awful lot of entries that looked like:

```
::1 - - [11/May/2009:23:21:16 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 5043 "-" "Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) (internal dummy connection)"
```

I have also checked the httpd.conf file, and I have seen the following settings:

```
# ServerLimit: maximum value for MaxClients for the lifetime of the server
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start   
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    8
MaxSpareServers   13
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients   256
MaxRequestsPerChild  50
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         2
MaxClients         150
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

I've been reading that I need to set MaxSpareServes to a value greater than MinSpareServers. Opinions are greatly appreciated.

Kindest Regards. 
Tom

Comment: Seriously, do people even use Google? http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/InternalDummyConnection

Comment: shame you didn't leave this as an answer! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it's nothing to worry about, you can just stop them getting into the log if you want by using the info from the link given already by Andri...

> If you wish to exclude them from your
>   log, you can use normal
>   conditional-logging techniques. For
>   example, to omit all requests from the
>   loopback interface from your logs, you
>   can use
>
> `SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127\.0\.0\.1" loopback` 
>   and then add env=!loopback to
>   the end of your CustomLog directive.